# TypeScript not following code logic: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'

Tags: typescript

The following code results in the error:

```
example/not-following.ts:15:1 - error TS2722: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.

15 run(true).maybe();
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Code:

```
interface Something {
    maybe?: () => void;
}

function run(isTrue: boolean): Something {
    const object: Something = {};
    if (isTrue) {
        object.maybe = (): void => {
            console.log('maybe');
        };
    }
    return object;
}

run(true).maybe();
```

Since this is deterministic code, why doesn't TypeScript follow it?

Comment: In TypeScript, why does it allow you to set a property as optional, if the code never runs. This is a perfectly sane question.

Comment: You could either define an interface with `maybe` as mandatory field and return that object or you check, whether `maybe` exists, like `const result = run().maybe;
if (result) result();`

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *"why does it allow you to set a property as optional, if the code never runs"*. What code never runs? Why wouldn't there be optional properties? The meta-problem here is that your question boils down to "why does `run` return `Something`", and the answer is that that's the definition you gave it.

Comment: You could fix this with overloads. Is parameter known at compile time?
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2EwAtQDmyA3gFDIXKZwCeARhAFzIAUAlMgLwB8yAbumAATANykAvqVIwAriARhg6EMihyWwAM4AVNU2Rg9bZhmx5C0uQqUq1IDTr3M66dABsIcEMeQAFOFCKcG4APKY4+CAE3Jbyisqq6lq6Mvou7p7ezP6BwMFhWBGEvGSUyAjKmmDI6HQAVhAK2QFBoeHmUbycJOJiZcAwrMlGJORllLUNCgB01PQo3ezMAsJcJWPj4xUgmhnTbugELADkcwzHbH2byL0bN3dQODJQKpONYGKSpHYshqlss1oDHYYm+6ngbk0EABZwgIKAA

Comment: @jonrsharpe Please elaborate on the "*The meta-problem here is that your question boils down to "why does run return Something"*", was not clear. Regarding why the code does not run, well, it doesn't run. Short answer is actually no? It is. Reference library is your opinion.

Comment: Sorry if that was unclear: `run(true).maybe()` gives the error `Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'` because `run(true).maybe` is possibly `undefined` because `run(true)` returns `Something` whose property `maybe` is optional. **You said `run` would return `Something`**, so it's not reasonable to be surprised by the result. *"Regarding why the code does not run, well, it doesn't run"* - a tautology is unlikely to clarify anything.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes that is the correct order of execution, however I am more intrigued by the fact that TypeScript knows (or should know) that the returned object *does* have the optional method as we put in the boolean true. It is as if TypesSript cannot follow this for some reason and I would hopefully like to know *why*. I am starting to think that TypeScript is a not a fully typed language, and if that is the case, what is the point of TypeScript.

Comment: *You've* defined an interface (in the general sense): `run` returns `Something`. The compiler will check each side of that boundary, and is perfectly capable of following through that logic, but **your definition** don't propagate that information. This isn't something the compiler is doing to you, it's what you asked for. If you want to express that `run` returns something different whether `isTrue` is `true` or `false`, as I mentioned above, you will need to add that information to the interface as [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads).

Comment: Once you define `isTrue: boolean` - it won't refine the type based on value function was called with. See my example above with overloads allowing "to follow the passed value"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was something called `generics`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

```
interface Something {
    maybe?: () => void;
}

function run<T extends boolean>(isTrue: T):
    T extends true
        ? Something & Required<Pick<Something, "maybe">>
        : Something {
    const object: Something = {};
    if (isTrue) {
        object.maybe = () => {
            console.log('maybe');
        };
    }

    // @ts-ignore
    return object;
}

run(true).maybe();

// @ts-expect-error
run(false).maybe();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess TypeScript is pretty smart, but probably not so smart that it completely validates these kind of runtime execution paths.

As an alternative, you could make use of closures, but I'm not sure if such a solution is appropriate for you.

```
interface Something {
    maybe: () => void;
}

function run(isTrue: boolean): Something {
  const object: Something = {
    maybe: () => {
      if (isTrue) {
        console.log('maybe');
      }
    }
  };
  return object;
}

run(true).maybe();
```

**Edit:**

Due to the downvote I received (which I do not want to object to), I want to additionally remark that for avoiding the error in TypeScript, you need to either:

- make the `maybe` function mandatory or
- check if the function is set prior to each invocation.

I personally dislike optional fields and I personally do not want to tediously wrap each call in a checking `if`-block. So I personally still prefer my current solution.

Comment: This won't allow the initial assignment of `object`; if `maybe` isn't optional in `Something`,  `{}` isn't a valid value.

Comment: @jonrsharpe . . . Oh. Yes. You are right. I missed that. Sorry. I didn't test it. (Shame on me.) I will check if I can fix it. (And I will test it before I post it.)

Comment: @jonrsharpe . . . I just fixed my code. I simply moved all code to the object initialization. (I have not run it, but at least Visual Studio's Intellisense does not complain about it anymore. So I carefully assume that it's all right now.)

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.

You get this error because `maybe` is optional, typescript has no way of knowing whether `maybe` is defined or not.

To fix it you'll have to check if the property exists first:

```
   interface Something {
        maybe?: () => void;
    }

    function run(isTrue: boolean): Something {
        const object: Something = { };
        if (isTrue) {
            object.maybe = (): void => {
                console.log('maybe');
            };
        }
        return object;
    }

    const oSomething: Something = run(true);
    if (oSomething.maybe) {
        oSomething.maybe();
    }
```

Comment: You could shorten your last `if`-block to: `oSomething.maybe && oSomething.maybe();` More cryptic, but more compact as well.